# Master page in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, tabcontrol, ui-design

I have to design a control_panel form. This will have many tabs. How should I design this? Should I make different new forms for each tab or is there a concept of Masterpage in C# WinForms?

Please give me your opinions. Thanks.

Comment: Is this WebForms or WinForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough to whip up something like this in WinForms, using a [`TabControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx), filled with several different [`TabPages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage.aspx), and a corresponding [`ImageList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.aspx) to hold the icons for each tab:

[image: Sample form with tabs]

Then you can just place the controls you want on each `TabPage` as you normally would. The designer has excellent built-in support for the `TabControl`, allowing you to simply click on the tab you want to switch to it as you could if your application was running. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/tabcontroltutorial11302005235835pm/tabcontroltutorial.aspx) on implementing tabs in C#.

If you need more extensibility and encapsulation than provided by adding individual controls to each `TabPage`, you can create a custom [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) corresponding to each of your tabs, and then place an instance of that `UserControl` into the `TabPage`. I don't really know much about MasterPages, but creating a base `UserControl` that all of your other `UserControls` inherit off (and then add their unique elements) of seems like it would provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You have tab control in windows form.
you can go through MSDN article for creating tabs.